# bad URI(is not URI?): only in production using ruby 2.3, rails 4.1.7 deploying on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I tried to put in production my website.
But when my URI is called by the app, I have the following message

`bad URI(is not URI?):`

When I'm running the app on localhost it's working but when I running the app on production it doesn't work at all.

How can I solve this problème, I already tried :

`uri = URI.parse(URI.encode(url.strip))` and other variable of this tips.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You'll need to add a lot more information for anyone to be able to help. Show the code that's failing, and debug and show the bad URI.

Answer (score 0):

I 'm trying to do that :

`client = LemonWay::Client.new wsdl:  "https://ws.lemonway.fr/mb/xxx/dev/directkit/service.asmx?wsdl",
                              wl_login: "test",
                              wl_pass: "test",
                              language: "fr",
                              version: "1.1"`

from this tuto https://github.com/lemonwaysas/ruby-client-directkit-string

Answer (score 0):

Have you try wiht the default test's login and password
login : "society"
pwd: "123456"

http://documentation.lemonway.fr/api-en/introduction/test-environment-and-default-accounts

Also , I might need to check which format you expect to get  (xml, json...) from the directkit